# font-weight: bold; does NOT work but background-color: yellow; works in visualforce PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I have a class within a `.css` file in static resource like so:

```css
.bold-font-thin-top-border-bg-yellow { 
    width: 100%; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-top-style: solid; 
    border-width: thin; 
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

There is an `apex:column` in a VF page, that is rendered as PDF, that uses above in its styleClass attribute. Everything works except the font is NOT bold.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Salesforce PDF engine (at least with API version 34).

Adding `font-family: sans-serif;` fixed the problem:

```css
.bold-font-thin-top-border-bg-yellow { 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, font-family: sans-serif does not work for cyrillic. I have to use font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';

Comment: @vladdihoney so weird I had font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';  and it got fixed when i change it to font-family: sans-serif; API version of page is 36

Comment: This does't work, could you kindly remove this answer? Adding a CSS file to a PDF page, with classes with font-family: sans-serif; and font-weight: bold; does not bold the element the class is applied to.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old thread, but there is bug with Salesforce PDF engine and font family "Arial Unicode MS" + "Font Family: bold" See below simple PDF image and you will see why it is working for other fonts and not "Arial Unicode MS"

[image]